# XML read text inside two elements

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<updater>  
  <version>1.0.7</version>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>

  <item>
    <url>some url</url>
    <name>file name</name>
  </item>

  <item>
    <url>other url</url>
    <name>other file name</name>
  </item>

</updater>
```

how can i get the value of url and name inside of both item elements? The full code have 9 elements with the name item. Please make the solution fit with this code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            string xmlURL = "someurl";
            reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
            reader.MoveToContent();
            string elementName = "";
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "updater"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) elementName = reader.Name;
                    else
                    {
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
                        {
                            switch (elementName)
                            {
                                case "url":
                                    if (nummer >= urls.Length)
                                        Array.Resize(ref urls, urls.Length + 1);

                                    urls[nummer] = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    MessageBox.Show(urls[nummer]);
                                    break;
                                case "name":
                                    if (nummer >= names.Length)
                                        Array.Resize(ref names, names.Length + 1);

                                    names[nummer] = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    MessageBox.Show(names[nummer]);
                                    break;
                            }
                            nummer++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

PS. If i'm unclear somewhere, or if you need more information then just explain what's needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var items = from i in xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
            select new {
                Url = (string)i.Element("url"),
                Name = (string)i.Element("name")                
            };
```

This will give list of anonymous objects corresponding to your item elements. Each object will have strongly-typed properties for url and name:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   // use item.Url or item.Name
}
```

Comment: @MasterXD `&dl=1 to be &dl;1` what is it? Which error do you receive?

Comment: &dl=1 is the end of the first url in the xml doc (dont want to give the full url since it is personal) and it is throwing an xml error when xdoc is trying to load the xml file from my server. "invalid token '=' expected token ';'"

Comment: @MasterXD this is invalid xml, because ampersand is a reserved character in xml. Ampersands should be escaped with `&amp;`

Comment: Where am i supposed to write that?

Comment: @MasterXD instead of `&dl=1` use `&amp;dl=1` in your xml. If you already have data in xml and cannot escape them before writing, then simply load xml into string. And create document this way: `var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString.Replace("&", "&amp;"));`

Comment: i just wanted to know how to move two elements inside an xml code, i dont understand any of those things. sorry

Comment: @MasterXD you're like a person who just wants to know how to pull a trigger without understanding what a gun is. Learn.

Comment: YES! Thx for making me angry with your last comment there. It made me so determent to figure out what was wrong that i made it work. I am testing things right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Xml.xml");

IEnumerable<XElement> items = doc.Descendants("updater").Elements("item")
                              .Select(x => new { Url = x.Element("url").Value, 
                                                 Name = x.Element("name").Value });
```

Comment: You can use an anon function like lazyberezovsky suggested.